# Telegram error 401: USER_DEACTIVATED after registration via telegram-cli

Tags: python-3.x, telegram

My target is to registrate telegram accounts via python script.

While i test registration by hands via telegram-cli (https://github.com/vysheng/tg) after successful registration account get permament ban after ~1-2min.

If i register via phone or official telegram client, after registration - login via telegram-cli is OK.
Problem only if i register via telegram-cli (https://github.com/vysheng/tg)

Start of telegram-cli:

telegram-cli -W -p profile_3 -k /etc/telegram/server.pub

profile_3 is a config directive in ~/.telegram-cli/config file.

```
profile_3 = {
config_directory = "~/.telegram-cli/3";
msg_num = true;
};
```

in ~/.telegram-cli/3 folder after registration creates files for auth. So after first login/registration i can move this folder to another stand and login without use phone number to account.

So may be someone know why telegram banned me and which client for registration is better to use or how to solve my issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think telegram might actually have banned you because you used your API ID. That's normal. All you have to do is just to send an email to recover@telegram.org explaining what will you do with that account and asking for an unban.